# How to mutilple duplicate rows compare in php?

Tags: php

i have some probelm in php when fatch data from database duplicate data is coming but product_id and product_name should be unique and data of product id display in same rows.

> `+-------------------+-------------+------------+----------------+-----------------+
>   | employee_id | product_id | product_name   | secondary_sales | date    |
>   +-------------------+-------------+------------+----------------+-----------------+
>   |           8 |          3 |  SENSI-TOUCH   |             345 |    2015-09 |
>   |           8 |         11 | MEDI-GRIP PF 8 |            1445 |   2015-07 |
>   |           8 |         11 | MEDI-GRIP PF 8 |             267 | 2015-08 |
>   |           8 |         11 | MEDI-GRIP PF 8 |             455 | 2015-10 |
>   +-------------------+-------------+------------+----------------+-----------------+-
>   4 rows in set (0.71 sec)`
>   
>   i want to accepted result this type
>
> `product_id    product_name     sec_sales    jul   aug  sep oct nov dec 
>       3           SENISI-TOUCH       345      0    0   345
>
>        11        MEDI-GRIP 8        2167      1445  267 0  455 0 0`

Comment: please share the code that you have tried so far

Comment: This is SO not santa claz

Comment: thanks .i am share code to you.

Comment: please help me any people.how to find any solution